# using vue-router to redirect to different pages

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue application which dose simple inserts and i am trying to use vue router to redirect to different pages for example when i load /postComponent and /userComponent they will be on separate pages not all in one page when loading the localhost:8080

app.js

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <router-link to="/postcomponent">post</router-link>
    <router-link to="/usercomponent">user</router-link>
    <router-view/>



  </div>
</template>

<script>

import PostComponent from './components/postComponent';
import userComponent from './components/userComponent';


export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
   PostComponent,
    userComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

routes.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '/client/src/App'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import postComponent from '/client/src/components/postComponent';
import userComponent from '/client/src/components/userComponent';


vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/postcomponent',
        name: 'postcomp',
        component: postComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/usercomponent',
        name: 'usercomp',
        component: userComponent
    },
];

new Vue({
    routes,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

postComponent

```
<script>
import postService from '../postService';

export default {
  name: 'postComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      error: '',
      topic: '',
      price: '',
      location: '',
      provider: ''




    }
  },
```

index.js

```
const  express  = require ('express');
const  bodyparser  = require ('body-parser');
const  cors  = require ('cors');

const  app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors());
const posts = require('./api/posts');
const users = require('./api/users');

app.use('/api/posts', posts);
app.use('/api/users', users);

const  port = process.env.port || 500;


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

im getting the following error
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Ka3.png

Comment: Just reminder : Vue Router is usually used for creating a Single-page Application

Comment: Use VueRouter's `<router-view>` component

Comment: i added <router-view> and im getting an error i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE ** :
App.vue :

```
    <template>
      <div id="app">
         <router-link to="/postcomponent">post</router-link>
         <router-link to="/usercomponent">user</router-link>
         <router-view/>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Inside Routes.js import statements and paths :

```
import PostComponent from "@/components/PostComponent";
import UserComponent from "@/components/UserComponent";

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/postcomponent',
    name: 'postcomp',
    component: PostComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/usercomponent',
    name: 'usercomp',
    component: UserComponent
  },
];
```

PostComponent :

```
<template>
  Post Comp
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: "PostComponent"
   }
 </script>
```

User Comp :

```
<template>
  User Comp
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: "PostComponent"
   }
 </script>
```

UPDATE * :
remove those unnecessary imports on app file

I think its better to first have a look at Vue-router at https://router.vuejs.org/

SPA stands for Single Page Application means that all of your components eventually will execute on a single *.html file. this means that in SPA, you cant just redirect your client to another url and perform another HTTP request and still be on the same Vue SPA!. because then you will probably get new html/css and javascript files to execute and render.all you can do is 1.use vue router to specify on which path, what component should render. when you describe your router using VueRouter thats exactly what you are going to do!, config your router and tells him on which path, what component you should render.

there is no way that you can redirect your client to another domain and still be on the same SPA and loads your components BUT !
as i can see in your codes there is a way to achieve what you want. there are some problems in your code but i'll show you how you can config two routes to achieve something like that.
i assume that you have those two components postComponent and userComponent ready.
first we have to import those in our `routes.js` :

```
import postComponent from 'PATH_TO_COMP';
import userComponent from 'PATH_TO_COMP';
```

note that you can use `'@'` as an alias for `/src` in your directory

first we have to specify two routes, for `/postcomponent` and `/usercomponent`,
we doing it by adding two objects to `routes` array in VueRouter, we can specify a name for our routes and we must specify a component which will render on that router,

```
routes : [
 {path : "/postcomponent", name :"postComp", component:postComponent},
 {path : "/usercomponent", name :"userComp", component:userComponent}
]
```

so now we have to implement our app file to say that where we want this components to render, we use empty `<router-view/>` tag to show that,

now everything is set, you can switch between routes using `<router-link>` tag like below :

```
<router-link to="/postcomponent" >Show me post component :)</router-link>
```

and you will see that when you go to `http://localhost:8080/postcomponent` your postComponent will render and sits on your `<router-view/>` !

Comment: try removing .vue extension at the end of the imports statements

Comment: the error went away but now the template is not displaying anything

Comment: you have to place router-view on your template

Comment: you mean postComponent?

Comment: and im still getting the same error https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Ka3.png

Comment: i think it cant find the routes.js

Comment: i updated my answer with working code of router.js , app.vue and two components. 
check your import statements and make sure their relative import paths are correct, the project structure is similar but you should check your own import paths to debug problem. - and try Vue.use(VueRouter) in you routes.js after importing them @IsaacBajada

Comment: im using the same code you added for postComponent and userComponent

Comment: i suggest you to create an empty project with vue-router config out of the box enabled using Vue-Cli ( vue create ... ) and examine files and their relation and i'm sure you will figure it out

Comment: i update my code in the question if you can have a look